# What does this phrase mean in Chinese “珉，石之美玉者”?

Tags: meaning, mandarin, traditional-characters, classical-chinese

Seems to be a line of poetry from ancient times?

Comment: Is there a way you could maybe explain that in English as I don't understand Chinese very well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence seems to be the explanation of [珉](http://www.zdic.net/z/1e/sw/73C9.htm) in [说文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi).

> 珉,石之美者。

It could be literally translated as `珉, the elegant one (the beauty) of the stones`; `珉`'s original meaning is `似玉的美石` (jade-like stone).